# Wrong behaviour of ComplexExpand and Conjugate

Tags: functions, complex

This input gives the wrong result

```
ComplexExpand[Conjugate[f[x]], {x}]
(*f[x]*)
```

instead of `Conjugate[f[x]]`.

In particular it works well with some functions, e.g.

```
ComplexExpand[Conjugate[f[x] /. f -> Sin], {x}]
(*Cosh[Im[x]] Sin[Re[x]] - I Cos[Re[x]] Sinh[Im[x]]*)
ComplexExpand[Conjugate[f[x, y] /. f -> Times], {x, y}]
(*-Im[x] Im[y] + Re[x] Re[y] - I (Im[y] Re[x] + Im[x] Re[y])*)
```

(note that `ComplexExpand[Conjugate[f[x]], {x}]/. f -> Sin` doesn't work) but not with others e.g.

```
ComplexExpand[Conjugate[Dot[x, y]], {x, y}]
(*x.y*)
```

Any idea how to deal with this problem? How can I get the correct output for the last example `f=Dot`? and for a generic function `f`?

Why the functions `Dot` and `Times` behaves in a different way?

Comment: The final question "Why the functions `Dot` and `Times` behaves in a different way?" is a good question, and should be separated into its own question.

Answer (score 3):

I think `ComplexExpand` works as documented.  If you want it to assume that `f[x]` is not real, you need to specify this.  For example

```
ComplexExpand[Conjugate[f[x]], {f[x]}]
(* -I Im[f[x]] + Re[f[x]] *)
```

Comment: Yes, this solve the problem in this specific case, thanks! But why there is a difference in these functions: `ComplexExpand[Conjugate[Dot[x, y]], {x, y}]
 ComplexExpand[Conjugate[Times[x, y]], {x, y}]`? Why I have to specify that `Dot` is a complex variables and I don't have to for the function `Time`? Is it connected to the NumericFunction attribute? I think it's important because I want to use ComplexExpand in an 'automatic way' that means that I'd like to don't care about the functions inside it