# Apply functions to a BlankNullSequence

Tags: functions, function-construction, evaluation, pattern-matching

I'd need to apply all functions in a list to a `BlankNullSequence` (`___`)

But when I tried

```
Through[{Abs, Dot, Plus, Power, Times}[___]]
(*{Abs[___], ___, ___, ___, ___}*)
```

it works well only with `Abs`. I'd like to have the result

```
{Abs[___], Dot[___], Plus[___], Power[___], Times[___]}
```

How can I have this as an output?
Why in my example there is a difference among `Abs`, `Dot`, `Plus` etc.?

Comment: `Through[{Abs, Defer[Dot], Defer[Plus], Defer[Power], 
   Defer[Times]}[___]]`?

Comment: Onlly `Abs` holds its argument if it's non-numeric. That's your issue here. The `Defer` kglr proposes will work. An alternative is to use `(HoldPattern[#[__]]&)/@<funcs>` because you probably want that for pattern matching anyway.

Comment: `Defer` is only for *formatting* within notebooks. Unless the output is copied and pasted back, the head `Defer` will stay in the expression.

Comment: @Giancarlo, this is unrelated to `BlankNullSequence`.  `Plus[x]` will evaluate to `x` for any `x`.  It can't be kept as `Plus[x]` unless it wrapped with `Hold` or similar.  What are you actually trying to do?  Perhaps you want `HoldPattern`.

Comment: @Szabolcs this question is related to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141557/wrong-behaviour-of-complexexpand-and-conjugate) I want to calculate `ComplexExpand[Conjugate[ff[x]], {ff[x]}]` and I have to specify that the functions inside ff are complex; for example: `ComplexExpand[Conjugate[Abs[x]+Dot[x, y]], {x, y,Dot[___],Abs[___],Plus[___]}]`. My idea is to search the functions (`Symbol`) that are inside ff, append to them the [___] and put the list in `ComplexExpand`

Comment: @Giancarlo Try `ComplexExpand[Conjugate[Abs[x] + Dot[x, y]], {x, y, _Dot, _Plus}]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is important to understand that functions will attempt to operate on pattern objects (like `___`) as they will any other, and sometimes this confounds the intent you had for them (the pattern objects).

Consider for example:

```
Plus[_, _, _]
```

> ```
> 3 _
> ```

This *evaluates* to `3 _` ([`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) `Times[3, Blank[]]`), which is not a pattern expression that will match `x + y + z`, because `_` is not treated specially in *evaluation*, so it is just like `Plus[x, x, x]` evaluating to `3 x`.

Now consider:

```
Abs[x]
Dot[x]
Plus[x]
Power[x]
Times[x]
```

> ```
> Abs[x]
>
> x
>
> x
>
> x
>
> x
> ```

What to do about this will depend on why you are preparing these patterns.

If you want to use all patterns at once I would suggest [`Alternatives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives.html):

```
pat = (Abs | Dot | Plus | Power | Times)[___]

(* unchanged by evaluation *)
```

Now e.g.

```
MatchQ[a^b, pat]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

If you really need individual pattern expressions you will need to prevent evaluation from making undesired changes.  The canonical method for that is [`HoldPattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldPattern.html) as proposed by [MB1965](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/38205/mb1965) in a comment:

```
HoldPattern[#[___]] & /@ {Abs, Dot, Plus, Power, Times}
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[Abs[___]],
>  HoldPattern[Dot[___]],
>  HoldPattern[+___], 
>  HoldPattern[Power[___]],
>  HoldPattern[Times[___]]}
> ```

Note: `+___` is due to an output formatting rule and not evaluation itself, and the pattern will still match `a + b` etc.  See [Returning an unevaluated expression with values substituted in](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7880/121) for more on this.

---

Recommended reading:

- [Pattern matching on Orderless functions inside Hold](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30152/121)
- [Why does Mathematica appear to change the head of certain expressions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56481/121)

Possible duplicate:

- [FreeQ and arguments of Hypergeometric2F1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64104/121)

Comment: nice explanation